# Python equivalent of java-streams piping

Tags: python, java-stream, pipe, list-comprehension

I mainly program in Java and I found that for data analysis python is more convenient.
I am looking for a way to pipe operations in a way that is equivalent to java streams. For example, I would like to do something like (I'm mixing java and python syntax).

```
(key, value) = Files.lines(Paths.get(path))
   .map(line -> new Angle(line))
   .filter(angle -> foo(angle))
   .map(angle -> (angle, cosine(angle)))
   .max(Comparator.comparing(Pair::getValue)
```

Here I take a list of lines from a file, convert each line into an Angle object, filter the angles by some parameter, then create a list of pairs and finally find the maximal pair. There may be multiple additional operations in addition, but the point is that this is one pipe passing the output of one operation into the next.

I know about python list comprehensions, however they seem to be limited to a single "map" and a single "filter". If I need to pipe several maps using comprehension, the expression soon becomes complicated (I need to put one comprehension inside another comprehension)

Is there a syntax construct in python that allows adding multiple operations in one command?

Comment: No, but you could customize a new class to achieve that

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pipe.html, https://towardsdatascience.com/dplyr-style-data-manipulation-with-pipes-in-python-380dcb137000, https://towardsdatascience.com/the-flawless-pipes-of-python-pandas-30f3ee4dffc2

Answer (score 5):

It is not difficult to achieve it by yourself, for example:

```
class BasePipe:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
    
    def filter(self, f):
        self.data = [d for d in self.data if f(d)]
        return self
    
    def map(self, f):
        self.data = [*map(f, self.data)]
        return self
    
    def __iter__(self):
        yield from self.data
    
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.data)
    
    def max(self):
        return max(self.data)

    def min(self):
        return min(self.data)

value = (
    BasePipe([1, 2, 3, 4]).
    map(lambda x: x * 2).
    filter(lambda x: x > 4).
    max()
)
```

And Gives:

```
8
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like to mention the [`streamable`](https://github.com/ebonnal/streamable) module I wrote (would love to get feedback!):

Your example would look like:

```py
from streamable import Stream

path: str = ...

class Angle:
    def __init__(self, line: str): ...

def foo(angle: Angle) -> bool: ...

def cosine(angle: Angle) -> float: ...

key, value = max(
    Stream(lambda: open(path, "r"))
    .map(Angle)
    .filter(foo)
    .map(lambda angle: (angle, cosine(angle))),
    key=lambda pair: pair[1]
)
```

- this is a ***typed*** module with 100% code coverage and no dependency
- the `Stream[T]` class extends `Iterable[T]`
- a stream is ***immutable***
- operations are ***lazily evaluated*** and cover concurrency, grouping/flattening, exceptions catching, rate limiting, iteration progress logging, ...